# Stripe Node SDK Error - Listing charges by transfer_group

Tags: stripe-payments

I have recently set up a system that pulls charge data from Stripe's API via their Node SDK using the *charges.list* method.  This method takes an options objects that holds a variety of request configuration properties.  I am using two of those options: **limit** and **transfer_group**.  My code looks like this:

```
  const charges = await stripe.charges.list({
    limit: 25,
    transfer_group: transferId
  });
```

It was working for a time and pulling the charges that were being made against the account, but recently it started returning an error, which I can't seem to find mention of anywhere.  I don't see any mention in the documentation either of there being potentially too many charges against a single **transfer_group**.  The error object looks like this:

```
  type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
  raw: {
    message: 'Too many charges with transfer group: `fbbb2c66-b79b-eb11-b1ac-000d3a14ec78`',
    param: 'transfer_group',
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Tue, 27 Apr 2021 21:41:59 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '183',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
      'access-control-max-age': '300',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
      'request-id': 'req_yg2EGfHSoNHsIN',
      'stripe-version': '2020-08-27',
      'x-stripe-c-cost': '0',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload'
    },
    statusCode: 400,
    requestId: 'req_yg2EGfHSoNHsIN'
  },
  rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
  code: undefined,
  doc_url: undefined,
  param: 'transfer_group',
  detail: undefined,
  headers: {
    server: 'nginx',
    date: 'Tue, 27 Apr 2021 21:41:59 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '183',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
    'access-control-max-age': '300',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
    'request-id': 'req_yg2EGfHSoNHsIN',
    'stripe-version': '2020-08-27',
    'x-stripe-c-cost': '0',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload'
  },
  requestId: 'req_yg2EGfHSoNHsIN',
  statusCode: 400,
  charge: undefined,
  decline_code: undefined,
  payment_intent: undefined,
  payment_method: undefined,
  setup_intent: undefined,
  source: undefined
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to correct this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known limitation of the Stripe API. I suggest you contact Stripe support directly and ask them about mitigations: https://support.stripe.com/contact